# Weighted least square regression - different ways of estimating weights

Tags: r, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression, wls

Newbie here.
I have a question regarding WLS regression.
Specifically, I've come across different ways of estimating weights in WLS regression, the most frequent ones being:

```
weights <- 1 / abs(fitted.values(model.lm)) 
weights <- 1 / (fitted.values(model.lm))^2
weights <- 1 / lm(abs(model.lm$residuals) ~ model.lm$fitted.values)$fitted.values^2
weights <- 1 / abs(resid(model.lm)))
weights <- 1 / resid(model.lm)^2
weights <- log(model.lm$residuals^2)
```

My question is twofold - **which of the above is suited to what situation (can you provide some references)** and how do you **check if the WLS corrected for heteroskedasticity** (**what do I look at**, e.g. R2, residuals etc.)?

Thank you in advance!